# How to pass the value of editable <td> to JS function, following onBlur event?

Tags: javascript, onblur

I have the following code which attempts to pass the value of an editable  cell, following an onBlur event, to a JS function, but when using `document.write` (for testing purposes) I get an undefined output instead of the inputted value.

```
        function saveToDB(id, value) {
            document.write(value);
        }
        
        function makeEditTableHTML(studentArray) {
                var result = "<table id='dataEditTableid' class='stripe' border=1><thead><tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Student Email</b></td><td><b>Target</b></td></tr></thead>";
                result += "<tbody>";
                for(var i=0; i<studentArray.length; i++) {
                    result += "<tr>";
                    result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][1]+"</td>";
                    result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][0]+"</td>";
                    result += "<td id=" + studentArray[i][1] + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(this.id, this.value)'></td>";
                    result += "</tr>";
                }
                result += "</tbody></table>";

                return result;
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `this.innerHTML`, not `this.value`.

Comment: Like @Barmar said - this.value applies to input fields (including select and textarea). Since your <td> is not an input field, you will have to use `this.innerHTML`